# Wordpress Settings API: saving multiple rows of similar data

Tags: plugin-development, settings-api

I've been experimenting with the [plugin options starter kit](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/plugin-options-starter-kit/) but can't find a way to save multiple rows of similar data using the Settings API. Example of what I'm trying to save:

```
_________________________________________
|____Order#____|___Image URL___|_Enabled_|
|      1       |   http://...  |    Y    |
|      2       |   http://...  |    N    |
........
```

Can this be generated and saved using just one register_setting? I can't work out how this would be done, especially with the format of the data being saved to the database.

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the best two articles i've read(i'm sure there are others to) on creating multiple options using the Settings API, one covers usage inside a theme and the other inside a plugin, but essentially both actuall cover doing the same thing(registering a page and having some savable fields inside that page).

- Themeshaper
  - [Incorporating the settings api in WordPress Themes](http://themeshaper.com/2011/02/18/incorporating-the-settings-api-in-wordpress-themes/)
- Alisothegeek
  - [WordPress Settings API Tutorial: Part 1](http://alisothegeek.com/2011/01/wordpress-settings-api-tutorial-1/)

Both have a few pieces here and there i don't agree with, i can't recall specifically what, but it's the nature of writing code, you're not always going to agree with the way certain coders approach particular things. I don't have time to run over them now and pick out what i'd do different, but both are still very good examples of how to use the API.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the 2 links, I'd seen Aliso's guide but not the Themeshaper one. I'll have a proper look over the Themeshaper guide as it looks the most thorough I've seen. I'll mark as answered once I've gone through it. Thanks

Comment: One more to add to the list (and a ping to remind you to accept @scribu's answer :) ): I wrote a [tutorial for incorporating the Settings API in Themes](http://www.chipbennett.net/2011/02/17/incorporating-the-settings-api-in-wordpress-themes/). Hopefully it is helpful!

Answer (score -1):

I have the same question myself and none of those two articles seem to answer the question.

Seems like a custom database is the only way to go ?

Comment: Er, what? Why would you think that you need a custom database?