# Find all strings between an enclosing shortcode

Tags: plugins, php, functions, shortcode, tags

I want to look for all strings in my theme located between my enclosing shortcode  [question] *desired string* [/question].

Then I want to output the so collected strings somewhere in my theme , e.g. listing all those questions and linking them each to their containing post.

The idea behind is that I am building a wordpress blog where I write down all the things i learned in blog posts. basically so far for myself. When I have questions about a certain topic I wanna note them down in the blog post between those tags. To find and answer the questions afterwards I want to use this filter function.

So far I was able to get one string between the shortcode using the [Options API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API) and this code. But it only lets me save one question at a time while I want to store all strings that are located between [question][/question] shortcodes. Floemi suggested using the [Settings API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API). I am trying to get my head around but there might be a more semantic solution to this.

```
 function question_shortcode($atts, $content = null ) {
    global $question_shortcode_text;
    $question_shortcode_text = $content;
    echo "<h2 class='question'>" . $question_shortcode_text . "</h2>";
    update_option( 'question_shortcode_option', $question_shortcode_text );
};
add_action( 'save_post', 'question_shortcode' );

add_filter( 'the_content', 'testing_var');
function testing_var( $content ) {
    $question_from_shortcode = get_option( 'question_shortcode_option' );
    $content = $question_from_shortcode . $content; 
    return $content;
}

add_shortcode( 'question', 'question_shortcode' );
```

Comment: Why don´t you use hyperlinks?

Comment: then how would you call all the hyperlinks from the blog posts in a list on a static page ( for example ) ?

Comment: Maybe its a misunderstanding, my idea was that i write something between those tags inside of the blog post and the question list should be generated automatically somewhere else.

Comment: I am trying to get my head around preg_match now and try to use that

Answer (score 0):

Basic idea of how this could be done:

- Hook into [`save_post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) or something else which is regularly run, but only by you (could get resource intensive otherwise)
- Parse your content and have a look for your shortcodes. [The Shortcode API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) could come in handy here.
- If you found your shortcode, save the text between your shortcode and the Post ID, probably by using [<strike>the Options API</strike>](https://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API) [the Settings API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API)
- Provide a special template/shortcode on your overview page, which reads those options and uses [`get_permalink()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/) to build links to your pages

This should help you for further researching.

Comment: thank you! I am gonna drop the preg_match idea for now, this looks like a more promising approach, gonna give an update soon

Comment: Can you help me with the part of saving the text with the Options API? I can't get it working...

Comment: Seems like the Options API is not the right way to go, it´s for singular entries. [Settings API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API) could be more useful. [Look here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/36873/wordpress-settings-api-saving-multiple-rows-of-similar-data) for some information on that.

Comment: Hey flomei I just edited the post and yes I think I am encountering the issue you are talking about - I am only able to create and retrieve a single entry. Gonna have a look at the settings API and your other link now

Comment: I will think about it after work. Probably can help you with some code then.

Comment: hey floemi I am starting with the Settings API now, didn't accomplish anything so far. Let me know when you have anything!

Comment: What about saving all the strings in variables using a loop or something and later outputting all that variables in an array?